# Keep recieving "error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token" error

Tags: c

So I searched around and from what I'm reading, usually this error is from some sort of syntax error but I can't seem to find one thus far.

This is the actual error

```
A1.c:14:33: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’
token
```

Line in question

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
```

EDIT:

Here's some code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>
#define LENGTH 12 
#define WIDTH 12 
#define TOLERENCE 0.1
#define SIDES 5



int NextDensities(double (*a)[WIDTH], double (*b)[WIDTH])
```

and the function is

```
int NextDensities(double (*a)[WIDTH], double (*b)[WIDTH]){




int     steadyState = 1,
i = 0,
j = 0;


for(i = 1; i < LENGTH - 1; i++){
for(j = 1; j < WIDTH - 1; j++){

 b[i][j] = (a[i][i] + a[i-1][i] + a[i+1][i] + a[i][i-1] + a[i][i+1]) / SIDES;
 }
 }


 for(i = 1; i < LENGTH - 1; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < WIDTH - 1; j++)
    {

            if((fabs(a[i][j]) - fabs(b[i][j])) > TOLERENCE)
            {

            steadyState = 0;

            }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question.

Comment: There must be something before that. It looks like a missing `}` or a missing `;`

Comment: In your case, you probably didn't finish a `struct` or function declaration somewhere above.

Comment: My guess would be a missing `;` somewhere inside of a custom header file, but as all those others said: more code would be necessary here.

Comment: ... take your pick from any of the Related questions.

Comment: Hmm I'm going through the related questions and seeing if I can find anything, no luck so far though.

Comment: show us the lines before `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`.

Comment: I added that in the edit. Everything above the main function is the first little bit of code.

Comment: well that was not obvious at all. The answer given by kvanberendonck seems correct.

Comment: I'm assuming that's sarcasm. I do apologize, I'm (I'm sure not surprisingly) quite new at C. While  it does seem to me like an obvious mistake  in hindsight,  I was quite confused because the syntax hadn't even crossed my mind because I assumed it was correct. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the last line in your (header?) file:

```
int NextDensities(double (*a)[WIDTH], double (*b)[WIDTH])
```

is missing a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: And you're right. I feel embarassed, I didn't even think  the headerfile was supposed to have a semi colon. Thank you.